# winform C# DataGridView How to Update Columns bound to Generic List

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Currently I have a DataGridView that is bound to a Generic List. So I have:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ProductBO.GetProducts();
```

This displays about 300 products and need the ability to update the price and quantity columns when needed. Whats the easiest/cleanest way? There must be some event like to use txtPrice_AfterUpdate() that can be used. Coming from a Webform backgraound and MS Access Im not sure the route to take here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a really expensive operation you could just refresh the DataSource, literally call that code again.

```
public void RefreshProducts()
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ProductBO.GetProducts();
}
```

Comment: msarchet - I dont see how that would work, wouldn't I need to call an update statement?

Comment: @Chris it depends on what you are doing. If you're making changes to parts of the data you'd need to save it, but reloading the data, which I hope would reload the prices should help. I'll add some more.